# Extending real valued to analytic functions

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, complex-analysis

Is there any way to extend a real valued function to analytics functions on a open set?
 I would think not since if $f$ and $g$ are real valued functions their difference $f - g$ is also a real valued function. Since $f$ and $g$ lie on the real line then any point $z \in f - g$ is a limit point in the open set. I kind of understand it visually but no sure how to put it in words

Comment: $f$ is a function $[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$, and you are asking if it can be extended to a complex analytic function $g$ on an open $U \subset \mathbb{C}$ whose boundary contains $[0,1]$ ? If $f$ is continuous, in most case the answer is no : $f$ will be the boundary value of $Re(g)$ (that will be harmonic). Consider $\tilde{f}$ continuous and extending $f$ to a closed contour $\gamma\subset \mathbb{C}$, and use the Cauchy integral formula $g(z) = \int_\gamma \frac{\tilde{f}(s)}{s-z} ds$ whose real part is the [Dirichlet problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_problem)